# How to remove duplicates records based on some condition in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have obtained this table by using multiple joins

```
E_name  s_date      year  h_value  l_value  update_date
  a    01-08-2012   2012    25      70       01-01-2012
  a    23-06-2012   2010    20      55       01-01-2009
  a    19-03-2020   2020   210      540      29-04-2020
  a    14-02-2020   2020    78      765      29-04-2020
  b    27-12-2018   2018    14      29       31-01-2019
  b    19-12-2018   2018    17      30       19-12-2018
```

I want to remove duplicates based on E_name and year.
if the next record has the same E_name and year as previous, then

1. row with most recent update_date will be considered
2. if both update_date are the same then the row with the most recent s_date will be considered

**Required Output**

```
E_name  s_date      year  h_value  l_value  update_date
  a    01-08-2012   2012    25      70       01-01-2012
  a    23-06-2012   2010    20      55       01-01-2009
  a    19-03-2020   2020   210      540      29-04-2020
  b    27-12-2018   2018    14      29       31-01-2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a group by and a row_number() on top

```
 Select * from 
( Select  e_name,"year", 
           maxdate,update_date,
         row_number() over (partition by e_name,"year" order by 
         update_date desc) as rn 
          from 
          ( Select e_name,"year", 
           update_date,max(s_date) as maxdate from 
          sample 
         group by 
        e_name,"year",update_date
        ) 
 )
        where rn =1
```

check this output link fiddle :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1646/23

Comment: sometimes " s_date" or "update_date" can be the same for both the records hence have to use both columns in case

Comment: if "s_date" for both the row is the same then I have to look "update_date" column to make a decision

Comment: Edited run it n check if it meets your requirement also if you want all columns use row_number() instead of group by

Comment: Getting an error " FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: edited was because rn was not referred explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

A query like below may do the tricks. Put your oriented data into a `Temp Table` and apply below query on your `Temp Table`

```
with MyCTE
as
(
  select
  E_Name
  ,S_Date
  ,year
  ,H_value
  ,L_value
  ,update_date
  , RANK() over (partition by E_Name,year order by update_date desc,S_DATE desc) as ranking
  from TempTable
 )
 select * from MyCTE where ranking=1
```